# Celery doesn't see tasks

Tags: django, celery

Here is my celery config:

config.celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
import sys
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')

app = Celery('config',
             backend=os.getenv('REDIS_URL', ),
             broker=os.getenv('CLOUDAMQP_URL')
             )
app.conf.update(BROKER_URL=os.getenv('CLOUDAMQP_URL', 'redis://localhost'),
                CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=os.getenv('REDIS_URL',
                                                'redis://localhost'))

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')


sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "applications"))
app.autodiscover_tasks()
TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Celery can't find tasks in following structure

```
project_name/
   apps/
       users/
           tasks.py
   config/
       celery.py
```

All my apps are registered in `INSTALLED APPS` and I'm using app registration via apps.py files.

Comment: Did you write `__init__.py` files for the directories? Are the tasks annotated?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can I annotate them?

Comment: With `@task` http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#basics

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm using   @app.task() and @shared_task() and __init__ files are present

Comment: What are the contents of `config/__init__.py`?

Comment: @dethos Something like this `default_app_config = 'users.apps.usersConfig'`

Comment: @Ernst HEy did u solve it? I have a same problem...

Answer (score 0):

According to Celery's [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), your file `config/__init__.py` should have something similar to this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```